# GWT Google Material Design out of memory

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

I created a wesbite with GWT 2.8.1 and try to use GMT. I followed [Getting Started](http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#gettingstarted) from the GMT demo website but without using the archetype. This is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.sample.sampleproject</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-project</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>Maven Archetype for GWT</name>

<properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.8.1</gwtVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-material</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>gwt-project</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Djava.io.tmpdir=${project.build.directory}\tmp</extraJvmArgs>
                <runTarget>SampleModule.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule</module>
                </modules>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this is my .gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='SampleModule'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!--<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>-->
    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesign"/>

    <entry-point class='de.sample.sampleproject.client.SampleModule'/>
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

If I run this and start the browser (Opera in my case, but tried FF and Edge too), it runs into an out of memory. If I inherit `com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard` instead of `gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesign`, the app runs fine.

I compared my pom with the one from the GMT archetype and the main differences are the additional plugins like GIN, GWTP and so on. Does GMT have a dependency on these or am I missing something else?

## Edit

This is the console output, before and after the browsers OOM:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project -Dmaven.home=D:\...\apache-maven-3.3.9 -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\...\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\m2.conf -javaagent:C:\MyPrograms\Jetbrains\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\171.4424.56\lib\idea_rt.jar=51493:C:\MyPrograms\Jetbrains\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\171.4424.56\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\...\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1.3 clean gwt:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Archetype for GWT 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ gwt-project ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ gwt-project >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:generateAsync (default) @ gwt-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gwt-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gwt-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\gwt-project\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ gwt-project <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.1:run (default-cli) @ gwt-project ---
[INFO] create exploded Jetty webapp in D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\gwt-project
[INFO] Super Dev Mode starting up
[INFO]    [WARN] Can't create cache directory: D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\tmp\gwt-cache-D16BCEB3891D540A576CEE39322956C5
[INFO]    workDir: D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\tmp\gwt-codeserver-3472297847544186841.tmp
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:23.951:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1942ms
[INFO]    Loading Java files in de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule.
[INFO]    Module setup completed in 16346 ms
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:39.681:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.14.v20151106
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:39.711:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63b84321{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:39.739:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2dc37227{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:9876}
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:39.739:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @17730ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:40.028:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.14.v20151106
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:40.339:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@3b083d20{/,file:/D:/.../IntelliJ/gwt-project/target/gwt-project/,AVAILABLE}{D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\gwt-project}
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:40.341:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@1c12cdcd{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8888}
[ERROR] 2017-05-28 08:56:40.343:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @18334ms
[INFO] GET /clean/SampleModule
[INFO]    Cleaning disk caches.
[INFO]       Cleaned in 16ms.
[INFO] GET /recompile/SampleModule
[INFO]    Job de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule_1_0
[INFO]       starting job: de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule_1_0
[INFO]       binding: user.agent=safari
[INFO]       Compiling module de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule
[INFO]          Unification traversed 21138 fields and methods and 2036 types. 2004 are considered part of the current module and 2004 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
[INFO]          Warnings in com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Arrays.java
[INFO]             [WARN] Line 1782: [unusable-by-js] Type of parameter 'd1' in 'int Arrays.1methodref$compare$Type.compare(long, long)' is not usable by but exposed to JavaScript.
[INFO]             [WARN] Line 1782: [unusable-by-js] Type of parameter 'd2' in 'int Arrays.1methodref$compare$Type.compare(long, long)' is not usable by but exposed to JavaScript.
[INFO]          [WARN] Suppress "[unusable-by-js]" warnings by adding a `@SuppressWarnings("unusable-by-js")` annotation to the corresponding member.
[INFO]          Compiling 1 permutation
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]             Linking per-type JS with 1984 new/changed types.
[INFO]             Source Maps Enabled
[INFO]          Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]          Compilation succeeded -- 19,773s
[INFO]       Linking into D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\tmp\gwt-codeserver-3472297847544186841.tmp\de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule\compile-2\war\SampleModule; Writing extras to D:\...\IntelliJ\gwt-project\target\tmp\gwt-codeserver-3472297847544186841.tmp\de.sample.sampleproject.SampleModule\compile-2\extras\SampleModule
[INFO]          Link succeeded
[INFO]          Linking succeeded -- 1,484s
[INFO]       21,783s total -- Compile completed
```

## Edit 2

Translation from left to right:

Task | Memory | CPU | Network | Process ID | JavaScript-Memory | CSS-Cache | Script-Cache | Image-Cache | GPU-Memory | SQLite-Memory

[image: Chrome Taskmanager]

As you can see in the image, Chrome is running a lot longer than opera. It crashes after more than 2GB.

Comment: You probably need to increase the available memory settings for your the GWT compiler/superdevmode. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430607/eclipse-gwt-out-of-memory-in-development-mode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430607/eclipse-gwt-out-of-memory-in-development-mode)

Comment: This doesn't worked out. Same result as before. Opera runs at nearly 50% cpu usage with memory usage slowly climbing up to 1000mb until it finally gives up with OOM. I don't believe it is an memory issue here, because the GMT archetype demo compiles fine within seconds. And I just used the standard gwt archetype helloworld example with nearly no webpages or elements and it will use more memory than the gmt demo? Mostly unlikely.

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood. 
So you are talking about an OutOfMemory error inside the browser not in the GWT compiler/SuperDevMode? This happens when you run the compiled code ? You could use the ChromeDevTools to see what is causing the memory consumption

Comment: Tried that already in Opera and recently in Chrome. (Guess both Devtools are the same?) I tried performance and memory profiling but when the OOM happens, the devtools just close. Only in network are some entries like the css and js files. Loading times of this files are < 200ms. Btw: I added the console output.

Comment: Did you try to run it in an incognito window to make sure that no plugin/addon is causing the issue ? Also you could try to check if there is a memory leak using [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/).

Comment: @Ümit Yes I did try incognito. I installed chrome only for this purpose here. Normally I use Opera. Unfortunately I cannot do a recording of anything. If I start one and stop it before the site crashes, nothing is displayed but a message "loading profile". The messaged is displayed until the OOM and the devtools are closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution but not the reason.

As I meantioned in the comments of the question, I used the quickstart [archetype](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html). I did not changed anything in my pom but in the .gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='SampleModule'>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
<!--<inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesign"/>-->

<!-- One of the following DOES work -->
<!--<inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesign"/>-->
<inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialBasicWithJQuery"/>

<entry-point class='de.sample.sampleproject.client.SampleModule'/>
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

Even that I did not use any of the GMT elements or styles, I have to load JQuery. So I guess it does rely on it. Unfortunately this is not mentioned in the docs. I always thought JQuery is optional.